# What is an alternative approach to determining the problematic root in the alternative quadratic formula?

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

When using the alternative quadratic formula to determine the roots, the root $x=  \frac{2c}{-b + \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}$ becomes problematic due to catastrophic cancellation occurring in the denominator.

Could you explain an alternative approach for determining the problematic root and then use it to recompute this root?

Please refer to the picture for the complete question.

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyIGF.png)

Comment: The complete question should be here, not just a link to another website. But it seems to me the alternative approach is, don't use the alternative formula, just use the regular one.

Comment: Maybe “rationalizing” the denominator?

Comment: @paul rationalizing the denominator gets you back to the usual form of the quadratic formula.

Comment: The problem with cancellation comes about when $4|ac|/b^2 \ll 1$ so that $b^2 - 4ac \approx b^2$. Doing it numerically you can check if this is the case and if so use a Taylor expansion: $-b+\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} \approx -2ac/b$ (here just to first order).

Comment: @GerryMyerson Right, but if catastrophic cancellation were to occur with this form of the root, then rationalizing the denominator would give you a formula where it could not occur (the discriminant would be subtracted from $-b$, which is by assumption negative).

Comment: @paul, rationalizing the denominator would give you the usual form of the quadratic formula, which is what I suggested using in the very first comment on this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both forms of the root formula, one of the sign variants may lead to catastrophic cancellation, while the other one is stable. Thus you always take as the first root the stable variant of the first root
$$
x_1=\frac{-b-{\rm sign}(b)\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.
$$
Then the second root is stably computed as $x_2=\frac{c}{ax_1}$ or with the stable sign of the second formula
$$
x_2=\frac{2c}{-b-{\rm sign}(b)\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}.
$$
One can go further and try to avoid floating point over- and underflow in the computation of $b^2$ and $4ac$ under the root, but these cases should not occur in "textbook" test examples.